# Azure service bus System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

We've started experiencing a problem with our azure service bus connection string, as of 04:57am messages are no longer being sent/collected from the service bus.

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: The token provider was unable to provide a security token while accessing 'https://biztechsoftware-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net/WRAPv0.9/'. Token provider returned message: 'The remote name could not be resolved: 'biztechsoftware-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net''. ---> System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenException: The token provider was unable to provide a security token while accessing 'https://biztechsoftware-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net/WRAPv0.9/'. Token provider returned message: 'The remote name could not be resolved: 'biztechsoftware-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net''. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'biztechsoftware-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net'
```

If I use the root connection string it works okay. The problem lies with the old connection string endpoint we are using that was created a long while ago. Is it possible that this old endpoint has expired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-acs-migration

> November 7, 2018: **All Access Control components are permanently shut down.** This includes the Access Control management portal, the management service, STS, and the token transformation rule engine. At this point, any requests sent to Access Control (located at .accesscontrol.windows.net) fail. You should have migrated all existing apps and services to other technologies well before this time.

Access Control Service was retired yesterday.
You have to use a shared access policy connection string with a shared access key, or use Azure AD authentication which is in Preview.

There is a migration guide as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-migrate-acs-sas